# How to create a bar graph using pandas Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

so I have created a dataframe that holds the len of tweets (in characters) for a specific user. I am having trouble creating the bar graph.Below is what I have:

```
data ={
    'Length of Tweets' : '0-32 ','33-64','65-96 ','97-128 ','129-160+ '
    'Length': [len(Tweeted_word032),len(Tweeted_word3264),len(Tweeted_word6496),len(Tweeted_word96128),len(Tweeted_word128160)]

    "Length of Tweets" : "0-32 ","33-64 ","65-96 ","97-128 ","129-160+ "
    "Length": [len(Tweeted_word032),len(Tweeted_word3264),len(Tweeted_word6496),len(Tweeted_word96128),len(Tweeted_word128160)]

    }
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

df.plot.bar(x="Length of Tweets", y="Length", rot=70, title="Length of Tweets")
    
plt.show(block=True)`
```

Comment: I frankly do know know what I am doing wrong because it is not showing.

Comment: df.plot(kind="bar")

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

// Defining Tweeded_word variables...

data = {
    "Length of Tweets" : ("0-32 ","33-64 ","65-96 ","97-128 ","129-160+ "),
    "Length": [len(Tweeted_word032),len(Tweeted_word3264),len(Tweeted_word6496),len(Tweeted_word96128),len(Tweeted_word128160)]
}

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

dataframe.plot.bar(x="Length of Tweets", y="Length", rot=70, title="Length of Tweets")
    
plt.show(block=True)
```

I think the main problem is that you called `plot` on `df` instead of `dataframe`. There were also some syntax problems with your data dictionary like not having commas between the key-value pairs in your dictionary. I also had to add parentheses to the tuples.

Comment: Thank you! But I have it not as dataframe but as df

Comment: Oh I see, but is it working for you now with the other changes I proposed in my answer? If it did solve your problem you can accept my answer.

Comment: It removed one of the problems; however, now it is saying section"(data=data)" is now undefined

Comment: Can you edit your original question and show where your dataframe `df` is defined, because if you've defined it before defining the `data` dictionary, it will be undefined. So put `df` after `data`.